# Why don't UISupportedInterfaceOrientations settings affect UIViewController behavior?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, bundle, resourcebundle

Xcode (4) highlights the UISupportedInterfaceOrientations settings, but no matter how I set them, it does not appear to affect a basic app's functionality. The Xcode templates insert commented out implementation for programmatically reporting support in:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations.
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

In my experience, this code has nothing to do with the app's bundle settings. So, I wrote the following code to automatically report support for orientation based on the app settings.

Why isn't this the default implementation? Did I miss something and this code shouldn't be necessary? (Any improvements anyone can suggest?) I might turn this into a category for UIViewController

```
/**
 * This implementation coordinates the app's orientation support with the app
 * bundle settings, simplifying the configuration of the app's support for its
 * different orientations. 
 */
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    static NSString *_orientationFlagNames[] = {
        Nil,                                        // UIDeviceOrientationUnknown
        @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait",          // UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,
        @"UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown",// UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,
        @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight",    // UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft [sic]
        @"UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft"      // UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight [sic]
                                                    // UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp
                                                    // UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown
    };

    NSArray *supportedOrientation = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"UISupportedInterfaceOrientations"];

    BOOL shouldRotate = (interfaceOrientation < sizeof(_orientationFlagNames)/sizeof(NSString*)
        && [supportedOrientation containsObject:_orientationFlagNames[interfaceOrientation]]);
    return shouldRotate; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a distinction here. The `info.plist` value indicates the orientations that the app supports whereas the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` indicates the orientations a particular view is available in.

If you look [`here`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW10), it is clearly mentioned that the `info.plist` values help iOS choose the initial orientation to launch the application.

Comment: Your link says, "...specifies the interface orientations your application supports. The system uses this information (along with the current device orientation) to choose the initial orientation in which to launch your application."

I'd only read the first part of the statement, but I guess that it is really saying that the settings indicate the INITIAL supported orientations. Do I interpret that correctly?

Comment: It reads that way, but this is not the case - If you do not specify all the orientations you need here, your app will not rotate to them, even after launch.  Someone please correct me if I'm wrong.